# Service module user update request payload

Tags: services

I am using postman to update user. Please suggest me what headers need to be send and what should be the payload structure in JSON format.
Should I send user object in params OR in body in postman.

Answer (score 1):

To update a user with the Services module, utilize these:

HTTP Method: **PUT**

URL: `?q=[endpoint-name]/user/123.json`

**Headers**

- **Content-type**: `application/json`
- **X-CSRF-Token**: use value available from `?q=services/session/token`

**Data payload**:

```
{
  "uid":"123",
  "mail":"new-email-address@example.com",
  "current_pass":"superSecret"
}
```